# Number recognition on Android

Tags: android, ocr

Is there any Android library that will recognize numbers from camera picture ?
I don't want use OCR its seems to complicated for such simple task.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817748/simple-ocr-app-using-android-camera