# Simple OCR app using android camera

Tags: java, android, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android OCR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

I want yo build an app that have an OCR scanner using camera and detect a text from a paper and convert in into regular text. a simple program. How i can do this? What is the simplest way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr

Comment: my simple OCR Tesseract app using android camera https://github.com/bieliaievays/Tess-two_example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was a time when this seemed like a bad idea, but doesnt seem like a bad idea.
 I guess u can use [Tesseract OCR Tool](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), an open source alternative by Google. How to integrate that in Android is simple via [Tesseract Android Tools](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/)

A good guide on how to do it is also well documented at http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/

Let us also know how this goes for you.

Comment: i dont have linux or mac, and cant compile that. there is no any compiled library? why this is so difficult to use? is there any java API of this with  .JAR extension? i searched alot about Tesseract but this is very difficult for me( compile, run,...) is there any solution?

Comment: unfotunately if u can compile and run then u could go with ABBYY https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Android